# How to filter map like array comprehension?

Tags: julia

With arrays, you can filter based on a condition:

```
[i for i=1:10 if isodd(i) ]
```

returns:

```
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 3
 5
 7
 9
```

but attempting something similar with `map` results in `nothing` values:

```
julia> map(1:10) do i
           isodd(i) ? i : nothing
           end
```

reutrns:

```
10-element Vector{Union{Nothing, Int64}}:
 1
  nothing
 3
  nothing
 5
  nothing
 7
  nothing
 9
  nothing
```

Comment: There's already a satisfactory answer, but a comment: `nothing` is a bona fide value, not an absence of a value. All functions and, by extension, all expressions must result in a value; it's just that sometimes, that value is the default `nothing`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`map` is a one-to-one mapping. So I'm afraid you can't do the same with `map`. Maybe what you are looking for is just `filter`?

```
julia> a = 1:10
1:10

julia> filter(isodd, a)
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 3
 5
 7
 9
```

Comment: Does this allocate an interim array?

Comment: @Alec you mean does it make a new copy? yes. If you want to filter in-place, use `filter!()`

Comment: @Alec you can use `Iterators.filter` instead if you worry about the allocation.